# How to replace all instances of "\n" in a string with linebreaks

Tags: python, discord.py

I am using data scraped from a website and making my bot display in separate lines. There is a particular string whose information has "\n" in between and I want to convert those into actual line breaks

I have tried replacing the '\n' with '+ "\n" +' but the output is still the same

This is an example of the issue I have, and not the actual bot code

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

cardName = "Card Name"
rawCardText = "This is an ability\nThis is another ability"
cardText = rawCardText.replace('\n', '+ "\n" +')

fullText = cardName + "\n" + cardText
await client.send_message (message.channel, fullText)
```

*I expected something like this:*

Card Name

This is an ability

This is another ability

*Instead what I get is:*

Card Name

This is an ability\nThis is another ability

Comment: surely instances of "\n" in a non-raw string literal are already linebreaks? Unless the rawCardText (use snake_case for python btw.) variable is being loaded from a source with literal "\" + "n", or in terms of python string literals, "\\n" or r"\n"

Comment: I am no python expert but apparently the "\n" strings that come with the text I scrape are raw and that is why they didn't work until I detected them as raw and replaced them by non-raw, as the answer I accepted suggested I did. The '+ "\n" +' is not needed and it was even a mistake, only "\n" is needed. _Edit:All of this refering to how Discord processes them on messages, I do not know if the same applies to a simple `print()` command because the other answer I didn't accept worked on python console but not on Discord_

Comment: Thats because the other answer assumed the text you wrote is the text you were getting. in python string literals, "\n" renders as a single newline character, that answer then used that single newline character to split on. Whereas what you actually wanted was a literal "\" and the letter "n", which in a python string literal is written as either "\\n" or r"\n".

Comment: Makes sense, maybe I could have stated what I wanted a bit more clearly. Regardless, I got my answer and now thanks to your help I know what the exact issue was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write `"\n"` as `raw string`:

```
cardText = rawCardText.replace(r'\n', '+ "\n" +')
```

Comment: I adapted your answer a bit, because at first I thought it would work differently, but ultimately this solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
cardName = "Card Name"
rawCardText = "This is an ability\nThis is another ability"
cardText = rawCardText.split('\n')
fullText = fullText = (cardName + '\n' + '\n'.join(cardText))
print (fullText)
```

[image]

Comment: This code works in isolation but when I try using it on my Discord bot it doesn't correctly output the linebreak